# When were extended records introduced?

Tags: delphi, syntax, version, records

In Delphi 7, you a record was nothing more than a collection of data grouped into one location.  In the last few versions, you've been able to add public and private members, methods, properties and constructors to them, treating them a lot more like objects.  What version was this extended syntax introduced in?

EDIT: In case anyone wonders why I'm asking, I'm trying to set up something that would be simplified quite a bit by using the extended syntax, but I want to make it backwards-compatible with older versions of Delphi, so I need to know which IFDEFs to use.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm pretty sure records with methods were introduced in Delphi 2006.

Answer (score 6):

I suggest you to take a look at [JCL library](http://jcl.delphi-jedi.org/). It contains a very useful jedi.inc file, where you can find all kind of definitions for features, specifically there is:

```
  SUPPORTS_ENHANCED_RECORDS      Compiler supports class [operator|function|procedure] for record types (D9.NET, D10+)
```

So, records with methods were introduced in Delphi 2005 (.NET) and Delphi 2006 (Win32)

Comment: Cool!  I've got the JCL, but I didn't know that was in Jedi.inc. Thanks!